# Migrations - Entity Framework Database First Approach

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-6

I have a existing database, and I am using the database-first approach in Entity Framework 6. Now, I have to update my database table with a new table.
I know that we can maintain migration if we use code-first approach.

Is there any way we can maintain migrations using db first approach ?

Comment: Probably something like this? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/modeling/designer/workflows/database-first#5-dealing-with-database-changes

Comment: Create a database project in VS, import your existing database, add your new tables, generate a DACPAC, then you just install the DACPAC at deployment time, and it will automatically migrate your database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a database project in VS, import your existing database, add your new tables, generate a DACPAC, then you just install the DACPAC at deployment time, and it will automatically migrate your database. –

Alternately, you will have to start creating and maintaining update scripts that add the new fields and tables etc and run them at deployment time